# Next.js on vercel – How to add a page under /index that is not the homepage

Tags: next.js

I’m building a website with Next.js and I need to add a page called "Index" under xyz.com/index

It works fine locally but when I deploy the website to vercel, /index shows the home page which is located under xyz.com/

Is there a way to make this work through rewrites or configuration on vercel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (`next 12.0.3`) the solution that works for me is using a rewrite:

1. Name the page something like "indexPage":

   `/pages/indexPage.js`
2. Rewrite /index to /indexPage:

   In `next.config.js`:

```js
    module.exports = {
        // … 
        async rewrites() {
            return [
                {
                    source: '/index',
                    destination: '/indexPage',
                },
            ]
        },
        // …
     }
```

Using the following folder structure only worked locally for me but not when deployed to vercel:

```
/pages/index/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to create a folder named Index, then under Index folder create js file called index.js.

You can see this image--

[image]